# Can't copy large file to SSD even when space is available

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, file-transfer

I have an Crucial BX100 SSD that has 78.4 GB currently free and I am trying to transfer a folder of size 75.2 GB from an external hard drive.

When the copying process is running the drive gets more full than the data actually being copied into it. For example lets say the copy window tells me that 40 GB is remaining to be copied which means that 30~ GB has been written to the SSD but when I check the remaining space on the SSD from 'This PC' while the copy is running I find that it will always say that less space is available then it should be. If 30 GB is transferred then the free space should be 78.4-30=48.4 but it always is lesser than that. Wayyy lesser, like around 10, 15 GB?

The copying process will eventually halt since Windows thinks the drive is full and I really can't fathom how. This SSD is basically useless to me now.

I have tried shifting the folder to my internal hard disk and then transferring, still same. I have tried safe mode and completely wiping the SSD (full 120 GB free) and tried and I'm all out of ideas.

I don't have the money to get another storage device and the SSD is out of warranty. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What filesystem is the SSD using? "Free space" accounting is primarily an OS issue.

Comment: Have you tried reformating it?

Comment: @grawity Just checked, the standard NTFS

Comment: @Azevedo Yes, didn't work.